# How to make three level expandable List view from JSON in Android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-custom-view, custom-adapter

hi i want to create three level expandable list view from the json. 
I have creted expandable list view up two two level but for three level i did not got how to do please if any body don please help me to complete it.
here is my code i have created.

my main Activity

```
String Tag="MainActivity";
private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ArrayList<String>mainlist =new ArrayList<>();;
HashMap<String, List<String>>  childContent = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

HashMap<String, HashMap<List<String>,List<String>>>  subchildContent = new  HashMap<String, HashMap<List<String>,List<String>>>();
List<String> childlist;
List<String> subchildlist;
private List<String> parentHeaderInformation;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new ReleaseOverviewReleaseAsynchTask().execute();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

    //ExpandableListAdapter expandableListViewAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mainlist, childContent);
    ChildSubChildExpandableListAdapter adapter=new ChildSubChildExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mainlist,childlist,childContent);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}



class ReleaseOverviewReleaseAsynchTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String jsonStr = Util.loadJSONFromAsset(MainActivity.this,"release.json");
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jo_object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    childlist= new ArrayList<String>();
                    subchildlist= new ArrayList<String>();
                    String release= jo_object.get("Release").toString();
                    mainlist.add(jo_object.get("Release").toString());
                    Log.i("main release",release);
                    JSONArray jsonArrayDetails=jo_object.getJSONArray("details");
                    if (!jsonArrayDetails.isNull(i)){
                        JSONObject jo_object1 = jsonArrayDetails.getJSONObject(i);

                        String builddate=  jo_object1.get("Build Date").toString();
                        Log.i(Tag,builddate);
                        String deploydate= jo_object1.get("Deploy Date").toString();
                        Log.i(Tag,deploydate);
                        String respindate= jo_object1.get("Respin Date").toString();
                        Log.i(Tag,respindate);
                        String releaselead= jo_object1.get("Release Lead").toString();
                        Log.i(Tag,releaselead);
                        String engineerlead= jo_object1.get("Engineering Lead").toString();
                        Log.i(Tag,engineerlead);
                        String testlead=jo_object1.get("Test Lead").toString();
                        Log.i(Tag,testlead);


                    }
                    JSONArray childarray=jo_object.getJSONArray("children");

                    for (int i_child = 0; i_child < childarray.length(); i_child++) {
                        JSONObject jo_objectchild = childarray.getJSONObject(i_child);

                        childlist.add(jo_objectchild.get("Release").toString());
                        Log.i("child release",jo_objectchild.get("Release").toString());

                        JSONArray subchildarray=jo_objectchild.getJSONArray("children");

                        for (int i_subchild=0;i_subchild<=subchildarray.length();i_subchild++){
                            if (!subchildarray.isNull(i_subchild)){
                                JSONObject jo_objectsubchild = subchildarray.getJSONObject(i_subchild);
                                Log.i("sub release",jo_objectsubchild.get("Release").toString());
                                subchildlist.add(jo_objectsubchild.get("Release").toString());
                            }

                            /*JSONObject jo_objectsubchild = subchildarray.getJSONObject(i_subchild);
                           */
                        }



                    }
                    childContent.put(mainlist.get(i),subchildlist);
                }


            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            //  Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }
        return null;
    }
```

my parent expandable list view is

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<String> parentDataSource;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> childDataSource;

private HashMap<String, List<String>> subchildDataSource;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> childParent, HashMap<String, List<String>> child){

    this.context = context;

    this.parentDataSource = childParent;

    this.childDataSource = child;
}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.parentDataSource.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return  this.childDataSource.get(this.parentDataSource.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return parentDataSource.get(groupPosition);

}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.childDataSource.get(parentDataSource.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parentlayout, parent, false);

    }
    String parentHeader = (String)getGroup(groupPosition);

    TextView parentItem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

    parentItem.setText(parentHeader);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if(view == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childlayout, parent, false);

    }
    String childName = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    TextView childItem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.child_layout);

    childItem.setText(childName);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

here is the expandable list for three level its not working for me

```
public class ChildSubChildExpandableListAdapter extends 
BaseExpandableListAdapter{

Context context;
HashMap<String, List<String>> childdata;

private List<String> parentDataSource;
List<String> secondLevel;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> childDataSource;

public ChildSubChildExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> Parent, List<String> secondLevel, HashMap<String, List<String>> data) {
    this.context = context;

    this.parentDataSource = Parent;

    this.secondLevel = secondLevel;

    this.childdata = data;


}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
   return this.parentDataSource.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parentlayout, null);
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    text.setText(this.parentDataSource.get(groupPosition));
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
    final SecondLevelExpandableListView secondLevelELV = new SecondLevelExpandableListView(context);

    String headers =secondLevel.get(groupPosition);
    List<String> header=new ArrayList<>();
    header.add(headers);
    List<List<String>> childData = new ArrayList<>();
   HashMap<String, List<String>> secondLevelData= (HashMap<String, List<String>>) childdata.get(groupPosition);
    for(String key : secondLevelData.keySet())
    {


        childData.add(secondLevelData.get(key));

    }

    secondLevelELV.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(context, header,secondLevelData));

    secondLevelELV.setGroupIndicator(null);

    secondLevelELV.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousGroup = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
                secondLevelELV.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;
        }
    });
    return secondLevelELV;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}
```

}

here is the second level expandable list view

```
  public class SecondLevelExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView
  {

    public SecondLevelExpandableListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //999999 is a size in pixels. ExpandableListView requires a maximum height in order to do measurement calculations. 
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(999999, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

hi friends please help me to create the three level expandable. the above code works if i use only ExpandableListAdapter.
in the above code i have used the childSubChildAdapter for three level then it is not working

i want to add the check box in each element of the lists and if i select a child the its parent should also be selected

here is my Json

```
{
"Release": "16.1",
"details": [],
"children": [
  {
    "Release": "16.1R3",
    "details": [
      {
        "Build Date": "",
        "Deploy Date": "",
        "Respin Date": "",
        "Release Lead": "Jl",
        "Engineering Lead": "LG",
        "Test Lead": "Dl"
      }
    ],
    "children": [
      {
        "Release": "16.1R3-S5",
        "details": [
          {
            "Build Date": "2017-08-17",
            "Deploy Date": "2017-08-25",
            "Respin Date": "",
            "Release Lead": "Jk",
            "Engineering Lead": "Ly",
            "Test Lead": "FD"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

please help me to in this problem. i am doing this type of work first time.

thanks in advance

Comment: with checkbox expandableListview not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use recycler view instead of Expandable list view ,because in case of large data expandable list view will create an issue ,specially in case of three level expandable list view.

and create an model class for each level of list which have a Boolean value for checkbox click.

Comment: i dont have any idea, i can you give some sample on it please

Comment: can u provide a copy of your json assets file

Comment: i have addded the Json please check it

Answer (score 0):

Hello for three level Expandable list view **you need a ExpandableListView with a childview containing one more ExpandableListView that is customExpandableListView** as we all known we cant place scrolling object in any scrolling view, i have done this in one of my projects,

**first Adapter is as follows**

```
public class AdminExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    private List<Child> masterData;
    private Activity activity;
    private int i = 1;
    static String masterId;

    public AdminExpandableListAdapter(Context _context, List<Child> masterData, Activity activity) {
        this._context = _context;
        this.masterData = masterData;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        //return this.masterData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
       /* try {
            return this.masterData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(AdminExpandableListAdapter.this._context,"Record not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return 0;
        }*/
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        List<Child_> dealerData = masterData.get(groupPosition).getChildren();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_admin_child_dealer_, null);
        }
        LinearLayout dealerchild = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_item_admin_child);

        int width = 380;
        CustExpListview SecondLevelexplv = new CustExpListview(activity, width);
        SecondLevelexplv.setGroupIndicator(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.group_indicator, null));
        AdminDealerChildExpandableAdapter listAdapter = new AdminDealerChildExpandableAdapter(_context, dealerData, activity);
        SecondLevelexplv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        return SecondLevelexplv;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        //return this.masterData.get(groupPosition);
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.masterData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = masterData.get(groupPosition).getName();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_admin_group_master_, null);
        }
        TextView lblListheader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.admin_master_group_text_view);
        lblListheader.setText(headerTitle);
      /*  lblListheader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AdminSelectMaster(groupPosition);
            }


        });*/
        ImageView settingImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.admin_master_group_item_image_view);
        settingImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UnSelectChild(activity);
                AdminSelectMaster(groupPosition);
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(activity, v);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.master_select_dealer_menu);
                Object menuHelper;
                Class[] argTypes;
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.add_account:
                                //  new AddUserAccountDialog(activity, _context);
                                new CreateDealerDialogSelectMasterAdmin(activity);
                                break;
                            case R.id.view_account:
                                new ViewMasterAccountAdminDialog(activity);

                                break;
                            case R.id.change_password:
                                new ChangeMasterPasswordAdminDialog(activity);
                                break;
                            case R.id.free_chip_in_out:
                                new MasterFreeChipInOutAdminDailog(activity);
                                break;
                            case R.id.lock_user:
                                new LockMasterDialogAdmin(activity);
                                break;
                            case R.id.lock_betting:
                                new LockMasterBetDialogAdmin(activity);
                                break;
                            case R.id.close_acc:
                                new CloseMasterAccountDialogAdmin(activity);
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Field fMenuHelper = PopupMenu.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
                    fMenuHelper.setAccessible(true);
                    menuHelper = fMenuHelper.get(popupMenu);
                    argTypes = new Class[]{boolean.class};
                    menuHelper.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", argTypes).invoke(menuHelper, true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w("LOG_W", "error forcing menu icons to show", e);
                    popupMenu.show();
                }
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
        lblListheader.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    private void AdminSelectMaster(int position) {
        final App editor = App.getInstance();
        editor.setCurrentMasterId(masterData.get(position).getId());
        editor.setCurrentMasterType(masterData.get(position).getUsetype());
        editor.setCurrentMasterName(masterData.get(position).getName());
        editor.setCurrentMasterMstrLock(masterData.get(position).getMstrlock());
        editor.setCurrentMasterCommision(masterData.get(position).getCommission());
        editor.setCurrentMasterLockbtng(masterData.get(position).getLgnusrlckbtng());
        editor.setCurrentMasterCloseAc(masterData.get(position).getLgnusrCloseAc());
        editor.setCurrentMasterMastrName(masterData.get(position).getMstrname());
        editor.setCurrentMasterPartner(masterData.get(position).getPartner());
        editor.setCurrentMasterMaxStake(masterData.get(position).getLgnUserMaxStake());
        editor.setCurrentMasterMaxProfit(masterData.get(position).getLgnUserMaxProfit());
        editor.setCurrentMasterMaxLoss(masterData.get(position).getLgnUserMaxLoss());
        editor.setCurrentMasterSessionCommision(masterData.get(position).getSessionComm());
        editor.setCurrentMasterOtherCommision(masterData.get(position).getOtherComm());
        ViewMasterAccountAdminDialog.ViewPartnership(editor.getCurrentMasterId());
    }

    public static void UnSelectChild(Activity activity) {
        final App editor = App.getInstance();
        editor.setCurrentChildId(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildType("null");
        editor.setCurrentChildName(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildMstrLock(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildCommision(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildLockbtng(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildCloseAc(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildMastrName(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildPartner(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildMaxStake(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildMaxProfit(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildMaxLoss(null);

        editor.setCurrentParentId(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentType("null");
        editor.setCurrentParentName(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentMstrLock(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentCommision(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentLockbtng(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentCloseAc(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentMastrName(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentPartner(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentrMaxStake(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentMaxProfit(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentMaxLoss(null);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Second CustomExpandableListView**

```
public class CustExpListview extends ExpandableListView {

    int width;

    public CustExpListview(Context context, int width) {
        super(context);
        this.width = width;
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width,
                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(900,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        /*widthMeasureSpec = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        heightMeasureSpec = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;*/
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

**Third childView ExpandableListView Adapter as follow**

```
public class AdminDealerChildExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    Context _context;
    Activity activity;
    private List<Child_> dealerData;

    public AdminDealerChildExpandableAdapter(Context _context, List<Child_> dealerData, Activity activity) {
        this._context = _context;
        this.dealerData = dealerData;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        //return this.dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        try {
            return this.dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childtext = dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getName();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_user_child, null);
        }
        TextView txtChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AdminUserSelect(groupPosition,childPosition);
            }
        });
        ImageView settingImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.master_user_child_item_image_view);
        settingImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(activity, v);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.dealer_select_user_menu);
                Object menuHelper;
                Class[] argTypes;
                AdminUserSelect(groupPosition, childPosition);
                //AdminUnSelectDealer(activity);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.add_account:
                                new AddUserAccountDialog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                            case R.id.view_account:
                                new ViewUserAccountAdminDialog(activity);
                                break;
                            case R.id.change_password:
                                new ChangePasswordUserDialog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                            case R.id.free_chip_in_out:
                                new UserFreeChipInOutDailog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                            case R.id.lock_user:
                                new LockUserDialog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                            case R.id.lock_betting:
                                new LockUserBetDialog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                            case R.id.close_acc:
                                new CloseUserAccountDialog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Field fMenuHelper = PopupMenu.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
                    fMenuHelper.setAccessible(true);
                    menuHelper = fMenuHelper.get(popupMenu);
                    argTypes = new Class[]{boolean.class};
                    menuHelper.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", argTypes).invoke(menuHelper, true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w("LOG_W", "error forcing menu icons to show", e);
                    popupMenu.show();
                }
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
        txtChild.setText(childtext);
        return convertView;
    }

    private void AdminUnSelectDealer(Activity activity) {
        final App editor = (App) activity.getApplicationContext();
        editor.setCurrentParentId(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentType("null");
        editor.setCurrentParentName(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentMstrLock(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentCommision(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentLockbtng(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentCloseAc(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentMastrName(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentPartner(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentrMaxStake(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentMaxProfit(null);
        editor.setCurrentParentMaxLoss(null);

    }

    private void AdminUserSelect(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        AdminSelectDealer(groupPosition);
        final App editor = (App) activity.getApplicationContext();
        editor.setCurrentChildId(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getId());
        editor.setCurrentChildType(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getUsetype());
        editor.setCurrentChildName(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getName());
        editor.setCurrentChildMstrLock(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getMstrlock());
        editor.setCurrentChildCommision(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getCommission());
        editor.setCurrentChildLockbtng(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getLgnusrlckbtng());
        editor.setCurrentChildCloseAc(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getLgnusrCloseAc());
        editor.setCurrentChildMastrName(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getMstrname());
        editor.setCurrentChildPartner(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getPartner());
        editor.setCurrentChildMaxStake(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getLgnUserMaxStake());
        editor.setCurrentChildMaxProfit(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getLgnUserMaxProfit());
        editor.setCurrentChildMaxLoss(dealerData.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition).getLgnUserMaxLoss());
        ViewUserAccountAdminDialog.ViewPartnership(editor.getCurrentChildId());

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
        //return this.dealerData.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.dealerData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = dealerData.get(groupPosition).getName();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group_header, null);
        }
        TextView lblListheader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_group_item);
        ImageView settingImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.master_dealer_group_item_image_view);
        settingImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UnSelectChild(activity);
                AdminSelectDealer(groupPosition);
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(activity, v);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.master_select_dealer_menu);
                Object menuHelper;
                Class[] argTypes;
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.add_account:
                                new AddUserAccountDialog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                            case R.id.view_account:
                                new ViewDealerAccountAdminDialog(activity);
                                break;
                            case R.id.change_password:
                                new ChangeDealerPasswordDialog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                            case R.id.free_chip_in_out:
                                new DealerFreeChipInOutDailog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                            case R.id.lock_user:
                                new LockDealerDialog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                            case R.id.lock_betting:
                                new LockDealerBetDialog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                            case R.id.close_acc:
                                new CloseDealerAccountDialog(activity, _context);
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Field fMenuHelper = PopupMenu.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
                    fMenuHelper.setAccessible(true);
                    menuHelper = fMenuHelper.get(popupMenu);
                    argTypes = new Class[]{boolean.class};
                    menuHelper.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", argTypes).invoke(menuHelper, true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w("LOG_W", "error forcing menu icons to show", e);
                    popupMenu.show();
                }
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
        lblListheader.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    private void AdminSelectDealer(int position) {
        final App editor = (App) App.getInstance();
        editor.setCurrentParentId(dealerData.get(position).getId());
        editor.setCurrentParentType(dealerData.get(position).getUsetype());
        editor.setCurrentParentName(dealerData.get(position).getName());
        editor.setCurrentParentMstrLock(dealerData.get(position).getMstrlock());
        editor.setCurrentParentCommision(dealerData.get(position).getCommission());
        editor.setCurrentParentLockbtng(dealerData.get(position).getLgnusrlckbtng());
        editor.setCurrentParentCloseAc(dealerData.get(position).getLgnusrCloseAc());
        editor.setCurrentParentMastrName(dealerData.get(position).getMstrname());
        editor.setCurrentParentPartner(dealerData.get(position).getPartner());
        editor.setCurrentParentrMaxStake(dealerData.get(position).getLgnUserMaxStake());
        editor.setCurrentParentMaxProfit(dealerData.get(position).getLgnUserMaxProfit());
        editor.setCurrentParentMaxLoss(dealerData.get(position).getLgnUserMaxLoss());
        editor.setCurrentParentSessionCommision(dealerData.get(position).getSessionComm());
        editor.setCurrentParentOtherCommision(dealerData.get(position).getOtherComm());
        /*editor.setCurrentParentAdminPrtner(dealerData.get(position).part());
        editor.setCurrentParentMasterPrtner(dealerData.get(position).getLgnUserMaxLoss());
        editor.setCurrentParentDealerPrtner(dealerData.get(position).getLgnUserMaxLoss());*/
        ViewDealerAccountAdminDialog.ViewPartnership(editor.getCurrentParentId());
    }

    private void UnSelectChild(Activity activity) {
        final App editor = (App) activity.getApplicationContext();
        editor.setCurrentChildId(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildType("null");
        editor.setCurrentChildName(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildMstrLock(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildCommision(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildLockbtng(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildCloseAc(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildMastrName(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildPartner(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildMaxStake(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildMaxProfit(null);
        editor.setCurrentChildMaxLoss(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```